# accessing child constant in parent class in java

Tags: java, cassandra, mapping

OK, so I have an interesting problem. I am using java/maven/spring-boot/cassandra... and I am trying to create a dynamic instantiation of the Mapper setup they use.
I.E.

```
//Users.java
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Table;

@Table(keyspace="mykeyspace", name="users")
public class Users {
    @PartitionKey
    public UUID id;
    //...
}
```

Now, in order to use this I would have to explicitly say ...

```
Users user = (DB).mapper(Users.class);
```

obviously replacing (DB) with my db class.
Which is a great model, but I am running into the problem of code repetition. My Cassandra database has 2 keyspaces, both keyspaces have the exact same tables with the exact same columns in the tables, (this is not my choice, this is an absolute must have according to my company). So when I need to access one or the other based on a form submission it becomes a mess of duplicated code, example:

```
//myWebController.java
import ...;

@RestController
public class MyRestController {

@RequestMapping(value="/orders", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public string getOrders(...) {
    if(Objects.equals(client, "first_client_name") {
        //do all the things to get first keyspace objects like....
        FirstClientUsers users = (db).Mapper(FirstClientUsers.class);
        //...
    } else if(Objects.equals(client, "second_client_name") {
        SecondClientUsers users = (db).Mapper(SecondClientUsers.class);
        //....
    }
    return "";
}
```

I have been trying to use methods like...

```
Class cls = Class.forName(STRING_INPUT_VARIABLE_HERE);
```

and that works ok for base classes but when trying to use the Accessor stuff it no longer works because Accessors have to be interfaces, so when you do Class cls, it is no longer an interface.

I am trying to find any other solution on how to dynamically have this work and not have to have duplicate code for every possible client. Each client will have it's own namespace in Cassandra, with the exact same tables as all other ones.

I cannot change the database model, this is a must according to the company.
With PHP this is extremely simple since it doesn't care about typecasting as much, I can easily do...

```
function getData($name) {
    $className = $name . 'Accessor';
    $class = new $className();
}
```

and poof I have a dynamic class, but the problem I am running into is the Type specification where I have to explicitly say...

```
FirstClientUsers users = new FirstClientUsers();
//or even
FirstClientUsers users = Class.forName("FirstClientUsers");
```

I hope this is making sense, I can't imagine that I am the first person to have this problem, but I can't find any solutions online. So I am really hoping that someone knows how I can get this accomplished without duplicating the exact same logic for every single keyspace we have. It makes the code not maintainable and unnecessarily long.

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not specify the keyspace in your model classes, and instead, use the so-called "session per keyspace" pattern.

Your model class would look like this (note that the keyspace is left undefined):

```
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {
    @PartitionKey
    public UUID id;
    //...
}
```

Your initialization code would have something like this:

```
Map<String, Mapper<Users>> mappers = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Mapper<Users>>();

Cluster cluster = ...;

Session firstClientSession = cluster.connect("keyspace_first_client");
Session secondClientSession = cluster.connect("keyspace_second_client");

MappingManager firstClientManager = new MappingManager(firstClientSession);
MappingManager secondClientManager = new MappingManager(secondClientSession);

mappers.put("first_client", firstClientManager.mapper(Users.class));
mappers.put("second_client", secondClientManager.mapper(Users.class));

// etc. for all clients
```

You would then store the `mappers` object and make it available through dependency injection to other components in your application.

Finally, your REST service would look like this:

```
import ...

@RestController
public class MyRestController {

    @javax.inject.Inject
    private Map<String, Mapper<Users>> mappers;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/orders", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public string getOrders(...) {
        Mapper<Users> usersMapper = getUsersMapperForClient(client);
        // process the request with the right client's mapper
    }

    private Mapper<Users> getUsersMapperForClient(String client) {
        if (mappers.containsKey(client))
            return mappers.get(client);
        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown client: " + client);
    }
}
```

Note how the `mappers` object is injected.

Small nit: I would name your class `User` in the singular instead of `Users` (in the plural).

Comment: I had one last question for ya.... how would you handle the accessors? in the accessor you have the @Accessor tag above your interface, then you need to write the query you are using like.. 
atQuery("Select * from keyspace_first_client.users WHERE email = :email")
Result<Users> getByEmail(atParam("email") String email);
Where you have to hardcode the keyspace in the query. Should I just do a similar model of maps for accessors to, do you think just running it on the correct client map will work without defining a keyspace in the Query notation? Thank you so much, you are extremely helpful

Comment: Yes, accessors work the same way: if you don't specify a keyspace for the query, they will use the session's keyspace. So basically you end up using the same pattern (one session for each client/keyspace).

Comment: thank you so much. I can't even begin to tell you how much you have helped out. I wish there were a way I could show you the code I wrote in the final product and get your opinions on it, see if there is some way to optomise it a little more. I am a PHP/JavaScript dev, but my company is switching to Java so I am learning it right now. Is there PM here, or maybe email? I would really love to get your input on this. Either way, thank you so much for your help, seriously.